# Get posts from all my Facebook Pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter, facebook-fql

I want to get the most recent updates from my liked Facebook pages (graph.facebook.com/me/likes/). I thought I'd got it working using FQL with the below statement

```
SELECT source_id, share_count,likes, FROM stream WHERE source_id in (select target_id from connection where source_id=me() and target_type='page')  LIMIT 100
```

However it seems that FB is filtering out a bunch of pages due to their various algorithms. Is there any straight forward way of getting around this? I'd just like to see all messages and decide whats relevant myself.

I was previously jumping onto every single page of my likes via the graph api, but obviously this gets a bit crazy if there are 700 odd likes in my profile.